# Normal Subgroups in a p-group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

How can one prove the following claim:

> Elementary abelian $p$- group of order $p^n$   have the maximal number of normal subgroups among all  $p$-groups of the same order.

Is is indeed true?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Induction works.  An elementary abelian group has the maximal number of maximal subgroups (kill the Frattini subgroup), and any non-maximal normal subgroup is contained in a maximal one.  Since normality is transitive in elementary abelian groups, you are essentially done.

Comment: Here's an MO post about it http://mathoverflow.net/questions/108581/number-of-normal-subgroups-in-a-p-group

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderGruber ! That's great!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm going to prove a stronger result: An elementary abelian p-group has strictly more subgroups than any other group of the same size.  Since every subgroup of an abelian group is normal this answers the question.

Let $G$ be a $p$-group of size $p^n$ and fix some $0 \leq k \leq n$.  We're going to bound the number of subgroups $H \subset G$ with rank $k$.  Any such subgroup is generated by $k$ elements, but can be so generated in many different ways.  In fact, by the Burnside basis theorem, a $k$-element subset generates $H$ if and only if it is a basis for the $\mathbb{F}_p$ vector space $G/\Phi(G)$. So for each $H$ there are always at least $(p^k-1)(p^k-p)\ldots(p^k-p^{k-1})$ different choices giving the same $H$.  Thus the total number of $H$ of rank $k$ is at most 
$$\frac{(p^n-1)(p^n-p)\ldots(p^n-p^{k-1})}{(p^k-1)(p^k-p)\ldots(p^k-p^{k-1})}.$$

But that formula gives exactly the number of subgroups of rank $k$ of an elementary abelian group of size $p^n$, so the maximum possible number of subgroups of a $p$-group of given size is realized by an elementary abelian subgroup.

Now I haven't yet proved that elementary abelian p-groups are the only p-groups which achieve the maximum.  To that end consider the case $k=n$. To achieve the maximum there must be one subgroup of G with rank n, but this implies that G is elementary abelian.

Comment: Just saw the comment, looks like Alexander Gruber already gave this argument at MO.

Comment: Your explanation is more thorough though :) +1

Comment: @NoahSnyder : Great ! I wasn't sure if the claim is even true! Thanks a lot Alexander also !

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand “so the maximum possible number of subgroups of a -group of given size is realized by an elementary abelian Subgroup". I don't know how we can get this conclusion from the above...

Comment: ...I think I have understood it...

Comment: Thank you for your good answer.